# Binding events based on ID with JSF and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I'm having an issue with JQuery and JSF/Richfaces.
I have an inputText component inside a form component.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<h:inputText id="myInputField" value="#{myBean.sampleName}" />
```

I have the following jQuery code:

```
MySite.supplier= function() {

  // Only attach event listener if the element exists on page
  if ( jQuery('#myInputField') ) {
    jQuery('#myInputField').bind('paste', MySite.common.handleMousePaste.bind(this));
  }

};

MySite.common.handleMousePaste = function(event) {

  // Need to put a tiny delay in so the element has time to get the pasted n content.
  setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#" + event.target.id).keyup(); }, 10);
};
```

The problem is the way my inputField is rendered. It gets the form name added to it and looks like this:

```
myForm:myInputField
```

So my current jQuery code will not find the ID to bind to.
The reason I do not reference it with full form name jQuery('#myForm\\:myInputField') is because I have a field called 'myInputField' in multiple locations throughout the site (Once on each page)

Has anyone any solutions to bind to the ID correctly in the 'MySite.supplier' method as well as in the 'MySite.supplier' method where I have event.target.id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awesomeness of the naming container in JSF.  When I was playing with this kind of thing, I used jQuery's endsWith selector ( the '$=' in the following code ).

```
jQuery('input[id$="myInputField"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: Sure thing.  This will work well as long as you are reasonably sure that the 'endsWith' value you are testing for is suitably unique.  If you have control over the css classes, Mark's answer may be better, but it looks like you've already explored that route.

Answer (score 1):

Could you assign a class to the text box and then simply use the class selector to bind your paste event?

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<h:inputText id="myInputField" value="#{myBean.sampleName}" styleClass="bindPaste" />

if ( jQuery('.bindPaste') ) {
    jQuery('.bindPaste').bind('paste', MySite.common.handleMousePaste.bind(this));
}
```

Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/cwSk5/).

Comment: I had it working that way originally Mark, but its not really ideal and could cause issues with future changes to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried settig prependId as false.

form id="myForm" prependId="false"

Comment: I haven't Hiraj. The pages are quite complex with a lot of Richfaces components, so I dont want to take the chance of breaking how some components render on the page.